# On Click icon show div, then click again hide Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navbar with a search icon. When I click it I want it to show a div where I have an input and a button, and if I click that same icon again, I want to hide the same div. So far when I click on it, it shows the div, however when I click on it again, it doesn't close it.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <i id="searchIcon" class="fas fa-search fa-2x">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
    <div  style="display:none" class="input-group date" id="searchDate" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker6" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker6"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
    <a style="color: black" href="logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-2x"></i></a>
</form>
```

And my javascript:

```
    $('#searchIcon').click(function(){
        console.log("searcg clicked");
        this.click?$('#searchDate').show(1000):$('#searchDate').hide(1000);
    });
```

Does anyone know why it doesnt close?

Comment: you can use .toggle() instead of how you are doing it, read about it here http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: You are saying `this.click ? x : y` which is `if (this.click) ...` — Well, `this.click` is a _function_, and since it is defined and non-null it always has a _truthy_ value, so the `x` part is always executed and the `y` part is _never_ executed.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery comes with the toggle method:

```js
$('#searchIcon').click(function() {
  $("#searchDate").toggle("slow");
});
```

```css
@import url("https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <i id="searchIcon" class="fas fa-search fa-2x">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
  <div style="display:none" class="input-group date" id="searchDate" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker6" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker6" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
  <a style="color: black" href="logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-2x"></i></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this and I think I can Help!

```js
function Test1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("searchDate");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<i id="searchIcon" class="fas fa-search fa-2x" onclick="Test1()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$('#searchIcon').click(function(){
    $('#searchDate').animate({
         hide: 'toggle'
    }, 1000);
}
```